# JSF Primefaces timeline add a value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, timeline

How to add a additional parameter / attribute in Primefaces timeline? I tested:

```
<f:param name="action" value="delete" />
<f:attribute name="action" value="delete" />
```

but unfortnatly that does not works in timeline, is it possible in diftent way?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What are you trying to do, and what do you mean it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

At Facelet, you can use an ajax event to send a delete request:

```
<pe:timeline value="#{yourBean.model}">  
    <p:ajax event="delete" listener="#{yourBean.onDelete}" />  
</pe:timeline>
```

At Bean, you can get/delete the underlying object with:

```
public void onDelete(TimelineModificationEvent e) {  
   TimelineEvent event = e.getTimelineEvent();  
    // >> delete 'event' here...
}
```

This you tell you which event is supposed to be deleted.
If you need additional parameters, you should prepare them in the model, in advance.

```
TimelineEvent ev = new TimelineEvent(yourCustomObject, startDate, endDate);
// add it to the model...
```

You can find how to delete stuff from timeline [at the official docs](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/timeline/editServer.jsf).
There you have a confirmation dialog if you need.

Comment: Thank you for answer. My mistake, I have written a example with delete but this is not topic of my issue. I know about the ajax delete event.  I have oneSelectMenu and I would like get the object from it and put into timeine model a a parameter, value...

Comment: you want to add an object to the timeline?

Comment: In timeline controler I have a query:  reservationsList=dao.Global.getQuery("from Reservation"). I would like to get object from selectOneMenu and insert it into timeline controler to change this query. Result should be something like this: reservationsList=dao.Global.getQuery("from Reservation where id="+PARAMETER). Where PARAMETER is a object from selectOneMenu in form.